# Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Conexion::prepare()

Tags: php, pdo

Hola buenas estoy intentando hacer un select de todos mis clientes pero me esta dando un error en el prepare y no se por que, y la conexion con la base de datos esta bien conectada y todo, no se donde esta el error

Aquí es donde tengo mi Base de datos

**clase BBDD.php**

```
    class Conexion {
    private $DB_HOST = 'localhost';
    private $DB_USER = 'root';
    private $DB_PASS = '';
    private $DB_NAME = 'gymart';
    private $conect;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $conecting= "mysql:host=$this->DB_HOST;dbname=$this->DB_NAME; charset = utf8";
        try {
            $this->conect = new PDO($conecting,$this->DB_USER,$this->DB_PASS);
            $this->conect ->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            // echo "COnexion exitosa";
        }catch(PDOException $e) {
            $this->conect ="Error de conexion";
            print "¡Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
            die();
        }
    }    
}
```

Aqui es donde hago todas mis consultas

**clase model ClientesModel.php**

```
    <?php

    class Clientes_model
    {

    private $db;
    private $clientes;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->db = new Conexion();
        $this->clientes = array();
    }

    public function get_clientes()
    {
        try {
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM clientes";

            $resultado = $this->db->prepare($sql);

            $resultado->execute();

            while ($row = $resultado->fetch()) {
                $this->clientes[] = $row;
            }
            return $this->clientes;
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            echo 'Error: ' . $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
}
```

Aqui es donde hago todo el control entre la vista y el modelo

```
**clase controlador Clientes.php**

    <?php

    class ClientesController {
    public function __construct()
    {
        require_once "models/ClientesModel.php";        
    }

    public function index() {
        $clientes = new Clientes_model();
        $data["Titulo"] = "Titulo";
        $data["clientes"] = $clientes -> get_clientes();

        require_once "views/clientes/clientes.php";
    }
}
?>
```

Y aqui mi index donde deberia verse todo

**index.php**

```
    <?php 
    require_once "config/BBDD.php";
    require_once "controllers/Clientes.php";

    $control= new ClientesController();
    $control ->index();
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estás creando la conexión de manera correcta, y almacenándola en $connect PERO, eso no significa que cuando creas un objeto de clase Conexion, ese objeto SEA UNA conexión, si no que contiene una dentro (en la variable `$connect`).

Para ello te recomiendo añadir la siguiente función a tu clase `Conexion`

```
public function getDb(){
    return $this->connect;
}
```

Y para usarla, cuando la creas puedes hacer algo así:

```
public function __construct(){
    $conn = new Conexion();
    $this->db = $conn->getDb();
    $this->clientes = array();
}
```

Comment: me ha funcionado muchas gracias